# error: void value not ignored as it ought to be while assigning value to a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, stack

Q.)You are given an array of size  and  queries. For each query, you are given two indices of the array  and . The subarray generated from  to  is reversed. Your task is to determine the maximum sum of the subarrays.

For example:
5 2
3 -1 4 2 -1
3 4
1 2 
this input would have the output of 8 9.
as:
Given array is {3,-1,4,2,-1}.

For first query L=3 and R=4. Now the array becomes {3,-1,2,4,-1}.

Maximum sub-array sum is 8 and the sub-array is {3,-1,2,4}.

For second query L=1 and R=2. Now the array becomes {-1,3,4,2,-1}.

The maximum sub-array sum is 9 and the sub-array is {3,4,2}.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stack>

using namespace std;

void Reverse(int *a,int l,int r)
{
    stack<int>s;
    int i;
    for(i=l;i<=r;i++)
    {
        s.push(*(a+i));
    }
    for(i=l;i<=r;i++)
    {
        *(a+i)=s.pop();
    }
    //return(1);
}




int main() {

int n,q;
cin>>n>>q;
int a[n];
int i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>a[i];
}
while(q)
{
    q--;
    int l,r;
    cin>>l>>r;
    Reverse(a,l-1,r-1);
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cout<<a[i];
}

}
```

I'm getting an error at *(a+i)=s.pop(); can someone explain to me  why is this error occurring and the way to remove it.
Any help would be appreciated.
PS: I know this is  not the complete solution of the problem.

Comment: [`std::stack::pop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) doesn't return anything (returns `void`), but you are trying to assign it to a value. Did you mean `*(a+i)=s.top(); s.pop ();`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first use `s.top()` to get the top element of the stack.
`s.pop()` only removes the element on top of the stack, effectively reducing its size by one. It does not return anything.

So when you assign it to `*(a+1)`, you have the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: made the change:*(a+i)=s.top();s.pop(); i'm still getting the array as -1 3 2 4 -1 whereas it should be -1 3 4 2 -1.?

Comment: Your question was about the error which I tried to answer. To get the correct output you have to debug the code and make the needed changes.